# Two identical unit tests, one of them returns "failed to start", the other passes

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have a simple unit test that asserts a 200 status code after testing an endpoint. I've confirmed the status code returns 200. If I only run a single test, doesn't matter which one, IntelliJ returns `Failed to start: 0 passed, 1 not started`. But if I run both tests, even when they're identical to each other (except for the method name), IntelliJ returns `Failed to start: 1 passed, 1 not started`. Any clue why IntelliJ refuses to acknowledge the true assertion of one of these two identical tests?

**Tests**

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    final ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);

    System.out.println("Test1:point1 hit");

    Response response = client.target(baseUrl + "/stats")
            .request()
            .post(Entity.entity("[]", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    System.out.println("Test1:point2 hit");

    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());

    System.out.println("Test1:point3 hit - Status returned: " + response.getStatus());

    response.close();

    System.out.println("Test1:point4 hit");
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    final ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);

    System.out.println("Test2:point1 hit");

    Response response = client.target(baseUrl + "/stats")
            .request()
            .post(Entity.entity("[]", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    System.out.println("Test2:point2 hit");

    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());

    System.out.println("Test2:point3 hit - Status returned: " + response.getStatus());

    response.close();

    System.out.println("Test2:point4 hit");
}
```

**Console output**

```
Started in 3693ms, on port(s) 25001 ##teamcity[testStarted name='PerfStatsIT.test1' locationHint='java:test://com.group.performance.osg.web.PerfStatsIT.test1']
Test1:point1 hit
2015-12-18T17:58:36.808Z INFO com.group.performance.osg.web.PerfStatsImpl postStats qtp322561962-16 []  [92bbf2d9-a324-49b1-b3cb-7b3ce0b0fccc] [669abd4d-bfe9-48ba-b131-dbffda2cbf66] [] [] Successful data input. 1ms null     
2015-12-18T17:58:36.821Z INFO com.group.performance.osg.web.PerfStatsImpl postStats qtp322561962-16 []  [92bbf2d9-a324-49b1-b3cb-7b3ce0b0fccc] [669abd4d-bfe9-48ba-b131-dbffda2cbf66] [] [] INCOMING http request POST 200 stats 364.07  
Test1:point2 hit
Test1:point3 hit - Status returned: 200
Test1:point4 hit
Test2:point1 hit
2015-12-18T17:58:36.883Z INFO com.group.performance.osg.web.PerfStatsImpl postStats qtp322561962-15 []  [e2511b78-4995-453e-8804-8d83b32152fb] [dafaf829-97e5-4828-a863-80cd3f4c6e39] [] [] Successful data input. 0ms null     
2015-12-18T17:58:36.887Z INFO com.group.performance.osg.web.PerfStatsImpl postStats qtp322561962-15 []  [e2511b78-4995-453e-8804-8d83b32152fb] [dafaf829-97e5-4828-a863-80cd3f4c6e39] [] [] INCOMING http request POST 200 stats 9.20  
Test2:point2 hit
Test2:point3 hit - Status returned: 200
Test2:point4 hit

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**IntelliJ test response**
`Failed to start: 1 passed, 1 not started`

Comment: Are you also using a real build system or just the IntelliJ test runner? It would be very useful to know whether or not this is an issue with your code or with IntelliJ itself.

Comment: @cjstehno Yes I am using Maven 3.3.9